# Trying to find the age of the youngest line officer on a ship MYSQL

Tags: mysql, timestamp, inner-join

I'm trying to find the youngest line officer on the ship Exeter using a timestamp and inner joining from other tables. I'm getting an error in my code at line two, which would be the timestamp command but I've never used it before so I'm going kind of blind.

Here is what I'm specifically trying to get: Suppose today is 1 March, 2328. Who is the youngest line officer on the Exeter? You may use an ordered list as your answer, but the age of each crewmember (or simply the oldest crewmember) should be displayed in years.

```
SELECT lastname, firstname, birthday
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'2328-03-01') AS age
FROM crewmember
INNER JOIN vessel
ON crewmember.currentshipcallsign=vessel.callsign
INNER JOIN rank
ON crewmember.rankcode=rank.rankcode
WHERE vessel.name='USS Exeter' AND rank.rankcategory='Line Officer';
```

Comment: Look at your timestampdiff syntax,thats have error. Add unit parameter in them .For more info http://coderlearner.com/Mysql_TIMESTAMPDIFF

Comment: Do you need to know their age? Or just who's youngest?

Comment: Yeah I need to know the age displayed in years.

Answer (score 0):

TIMESTAMPDIFF return the difference between two date columns .

You have only a value

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR,'2328-03-01') AS age
```

try adding the second date eg :

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH,'2009-05-18','2009-07-29');
```